# STM32H750B-DK output pins don't work while using the display

Tags: gpio, stm32cubeide, stm32h750vbt

I am trying to make a relay driver with STM32H750DB-K, so I could switch the relays with toggle buttons on display, but I have a difficulty writing on digital pins. I am working with STM32CubeIDE.

When I don't generate code from TouchGFX (so starting from scratch) and just write on output pin E3 (by default on low) calling the function HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_SET); in while function of main.c the voltage on pin E3 is set to 3.3V as expected.
But when I generate a simple code with TouchGFX (just a toggle button) and write function HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_SET); in while function of main.c (which is in TouchGFX folder) the voltage on pin E3 is 0V (as set in MX_GPIO_Init). If I set pin by default on high, it sets on 3.3V and if I try to set it to low in while function it stays on 3.3V.
I tried this on several pins, but it is always the same.

Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

---

This is GPIO_Init without the use of display:

```
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOI_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOI, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PE3 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_3;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PI8 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOI, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}
```

And this is GPIO_Init when I generate TouchGFX code for display:

```
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOK_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOG_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOI_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOJ_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LCD_DE_GPIO_Port, LCD_DE_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOI, GPIO_PIN_8|RENDER_TIME_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LCD_BL_CTRL_GPIO_Port, LCD_BL_CTRL_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LCD_RESET_GPIO_Port, LCD_RESET_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(VSYNC_FREQ_GPIO_Port, VSYNC_FREQ_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : LCD_DE_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LCD_DE_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(LCD_DE_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PE3 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_3;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PI8 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOI, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : RENDER_TIME_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = RENDER_TIME_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(RENDER_TIME_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : LCD_BL_CTRL_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LCD_BL_CTRL_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(LCD_BL_CTRL_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : LCD_RESET_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LCD_RESET_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(LCD_RESET_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : VSYNC_FREQ_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = VSYNC_FREQ_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(VSYNC_FREQ_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}
```

Comment: Please add minimalistic example code for both cases (including init routine).

Comment: Check how the pins is being initialized by CubeMX. It should have generated some code somewhere to make calls to `HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, .....)`.

Comment: I edited the question with addition of MX_GPIO_Init function for usage of display (with TouchGFX generated code) and without it. In addition to GPIO_init the next init functions are called when TouchGFX code is generated:
static void MX_CRC_Init(void);
static void MX_LTDC_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA2D_Init(void);
static void MX_QUADSPI_Init(void);
static void MX_FMC_Init(void);

Comment: The inits look fine. I'm assuming you've already checked that `RENDER_TIME_GPIO_Port.RENDER_TIME_Pin` etc. don't conflict. Are you able to debug? If so, you could check the state of the GPIO registers.